# Retaining unknown keys during JSON (de)serialization with Codable

Tags: json, swift

I'm using `Codable` to convert between JSON and a Swift object. The process goes like this:

1. JSON -> Swift object
2. Modify the Swift object
3. Swift object -> JSON

The issue is that if the original JSON contains unknown keys, they are removed during the conversion to the Swift object and then back to JSON. Is there a way to retain these unknown keys during the conversion process?

Comment: I haven't thought about this deeply enough to have an answer-worthy solution; however, `KeyedDecodingContainer` does have an `allKeys` property.  You'd probably have to explicitly implement `init(from:)` and `encode(to:)` rather than relying on synthesized conformance, but you could use `allKeys` to extract keys your object doesn't know about saving their values in a `Dictionary`, then when encoding, after encoding the values you object knows about,  iterate through that dictionary to encode the others.

Comment: Alternatively you could externally first decode to a `Dictionary` using `JSONSerialization`, then decode to your object using `JSONDecoder`.  Then when you encode your object, you'd decode that into another `Dictionary` using `JSONSerialization` and merge that into the first dictionary, and encode the merged dictionary to get your final JSON.  That has the advantage of still being able to use synthesized `Codable` conformance, but at the cost of adding additional decoding and encoding steps separately.

Comment: Thanks, seems like `allKeys` only contains keys which are manually listed in a `CodingKey` enums. I'll probably use just `JSONSerialization` and store the original JSON in the Swift object as a `[String: Any]` dictionary.